# Pontuação de boliche em C;

Tags: c

Sou iniciante em `C` e estou tendo problemas em um exercício, não consigo ver uma forma de solucioná-lo.
Seguinte:

Em cada etapa o jogador dispõe de 2 bolas com as quais deve derrubar 10 pinos. A etapa termina quando: o jogador derrubar os 10 pinos ou o jogador usar as 2 bolas.

```
i = bola1;
j = bola2;

pontuação
    1 – STRIKE   se i = 10 (a 2a bola não é usada); 
    2 – SPARE    se i < 10, mas  i + j = 10;
    3 – MISS       se i + j < 10;
Valor pontuação
STRIKE - 10 + números de pinos que o jogador derrubar com as duas bolas  seguintes.  
SPARE - 10 + número de pinos derrubados com a próxima bola   
MISS - i + j


a) Leia uma seqüência de números inteiros que descreve  um jogo completo. O i-ésimo termo da sequência é o número de pinos derrubados pela i-ésima bola. Qual será o tamanho máximo da seqüência? 
b) Identifique a quantidade de pinos derrubados por cada etapa e classifique como STRIKE, SPARE ou MISS. 
c) Calcule o número de pontos por etapa 
d) Calcule o total de pontos no jogo 
e) Imprima os resultados   

Numero de exemplo;
    1o jogo: 10, 9, 1, 6, 3, 7, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 1, 0, 9, 1;   
    2o jogo: 9, 1, 0, 10, 10, 10, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 2, 10, 9, 0, 9, 1, 2; 
    3o jogo: 10, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 10, 7, 3, 4, 6, 10, 9, 1, 10, 7, 3;
```

Bom, tentei usar um `for` pra verificar o valor de cada posição do vetor, até aí tudo bem, meu problema é para comparar os dois próximos valores caso o primeiro não seja um Strike.

```
main() {
    int game1[20] = {10, 9, 1, 6, 3, 7, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 10, 9, 1};
    int game2[18] = {9, 1, 0, 10, 10, 10, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 2, 10, 9, 0, 9, 1, 2};
    int game3[17] = {10, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 10, 7, 3, 4, 6, 10, 9, 1, 10, 7, 3};
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<20; j++) {
            if(game1[i] == 10) {
                printf("Strike");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Esse é o código que comecei a fazer, porém minha duvida é mais na parte logica, como comparar o valor de i e j para saber se é um Strike, Spare ou Miss;

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste o código que você já tentou para o pessoal poder te ajudar, ;)

Comment: editado, valeu ^^

Comment: Não vejo para que usar 2 for, basta 1 e seguir sua lógica: se game1[i] = 10 então é strike, senão se game1[i] + game1[i+1] = 10 então é spare, e assim vai. Só tem de se atentar ao game1[i + 1], pois este vai estourar o vetor quando tiver no final, então tens de veriricar.

Comment: tentei do jeito que voce disse luiz henrique, ate funcionou, porem, por exemplo, depois de comparar o primeiro 10, ele passa pra comparar o 9 com o 1, e depois o 1 com o 6. Sendo que apos comparar o 9 com o 1 ele compare o 6 com o 3 respectivamente. Nao sei se deu pra entender. Mas sua resposta ja me deu uma boa luz aqui. Obrigado ^^

Answer (score 2):

Para que ele ande mais que uma casa basta incrementar o `i` quando não for "STRIKE".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define JOGADAS 20

int main(void) {
    int game1[JOGADAS] = {10, 9, 1, 6, 3, 7, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 10, 9, 1};
    //int game2[18] = {9, 1, 0, 10, 10, 10, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 2, 10, 9, 0, 9, 1, 2};
    //int game3[17] = {10, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 10, 7, 3, 4, 6, 10, 9, 1, 10, 7, 3};
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<JOGADAS; i++) {
        if(game1[i] == 10) {
            printf("STRIKE\n");
        }
        else if (game1[i]+game1[i+1] == 10) {
            printf("SPARE\n");
            i++; //avança mais uma casa para o próximo jogo.
        }
        else {
            printf("MISS\n");
            i++; //avança mais uma casa para o próximo jogo.
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [aqui a funcionar](http://ideone.com/kvlovK).

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, alias, muito origado a todo mundo que ajudou. Deu certo aqui tambem, agora o restante do exercicio consigo fazer numa boa. ^^

Comment: @YutoSan Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, você deveria rever a estrutura que você utilizou para guardar os dados de cada jogada. Da forma que os dados estão sendo guardados, você não consegue saber a que rodada a pontuação se refere a menos que você faça uma execução completa do algoritmo, o que o torna extremamente ineficiente (afinal guardar o resultado das jogadas serve exatamente para você não precisar fazer tudo de novo).

Recomendo que você crie uma estrutura personalizada, por exemplo:

```
struct rodada{
    int jogada1;
    int jogada2;
};

struct rodada game1[20];
```

Dessa forma a informação sobre o resultado da i-ésima jogada estará a apenas uma instrução de distância. Quer dizer, basta você fazer um `resultado = game1[10].jogada1;` para saber se foi um strike ou não. Não há necessidade de ler **TODAS AS JOGADAS** até a décima para obter uma informação tão simples.

Recomendo também definir algum valor inválido (como um "x" ou uma variável booleana) na segunda jogada para sinalizar que houve um strike na rodada.

**Obs:** Desculpe se houver algum erro no código, tem alguns anos que não programo em C.

**Obs2:** Você também poderia adicionar uma outra variável na struct para manter a pontuação parcial de cada rodada.